# How do I draw a scrolling background?

Tags: android, opengl-es

How can I draw background tile in my 2D side-scrolling game? Is that loop logical for OpenGL es? My tile 2400x480. Also I want to use parallax scrolling for my game.

```
batcher.beginBatch(Assets.background);
for(int i=0; i<100; i++)
    batcher.drawSprite(0+2400*i, 240, 2400, 480, Assets.backgroundRegion);

batcher.endBatch();
```

---

### UPDATE

And thats my onDrawFrame.I'm sending deltaTime for fps control.

```
public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {                
    GLGameState state = null;

    synchronized(stateChanged) {
        state = this.state;
    }

    if(state == GLGameState.Running) {
        float deltaTime = (System.nanoTime()-startTime) / 1000000000.0f;
        startTime = System.nanoTime();

        screen.update(deltaTime);
        screen.present(deltaTime);
    }

    if(state == GLGameState.Paused) {
        screen.pause();            
        synchronized(stateChanged) {
            this.state = GLGameState.Idle;
            stateChanged.notifyAll();
        }
    }

    if(state == GLGameState.Finished) {
        screen.pause();
        screen.dispose();
        synchronized(stateChanged) {
            this.state = GLGameState.Idle;
            stateChanged.notifyAll();
        }            
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you not getting the results you want with your current code? What have you tried already? What about it isn't working?

Comment: @Byte56 i think thats not logical.Because i draw background already for 2400*100 pixels.I'm searching for better idea.

Comment: In android sample application Lunar Lader they have explain how to move background of a game. Using that [sample](http://androidtrainningcenter.blogspot.in/2012/12/android-game-development-moving-or.html), this article explain this concept very well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this code, you are drawing the background 100 times in 100 different places in **1** frame. Learn how to properly use a game loop to run your game (here's a good article: http://www.koonsolo.com/news/dewitters-gameloop/). Your going to want to update the background's position in each update tick of your game loop and draw it at its current location in each frame.

**Post-Update Edit**: So in `screen.update(deltaTime);` you'll want to change the current background position with something like:
`background.translate(BACKGROUND_SCROLL_SPEED * deltaTime, 0)`

Then, in `screen.present(deltaTime);` draw the background with:   `batcher.drawSprite(background.getX(), 240, 2400, 480, Assets.backgroundRegion);`

Let me know if you still have questions.

Comment: i'm using a different game loop already in my upper class.Are there any other solution for this?

Comment: What does your game loop look like? Because you need to be changing the position in the update section and drawing it in its current position in the draw section. This is the best (and pretty much only) way to make real-time games. If you edit your question to show what your game loop looks like, I will help you understand how to do this.

Comment: I have updated my question.

Comment: @droidmachine I updated my answer.

Comment: I have used this but no solution:
in update():
backx+=200*deltaTime;

in present():
batcher.drawSprite(backx, 240, 2400, 480, Assets.backgroundRegion);

Comment: What do you mean no solution? What is still going wrong? Perhaps 200 is far too much to multiply by. I was thinking a number between 0 and 1 might be right.

Comment: it always draws only one tile.

Comment: How about adding a screenshot? Your problem is extremely vague. You have to be as specific as possible to get good help from this site. Were you drawing your background as one large image or as a set of tiles? I assumed a large image because backgrounds are not normally constructed from tiles. The level structure usually is but not the background.

Comment: I have an large tillable image(2400x480).And it draws this image only one time.

Comment: Is 2400X480 larger than your scree? Because if so, you only need to draw it once at a time. If the player can't view it there is no since drawing it.

Comment: No.I'm adding this tile again and again in phone screen.I'm drawing it and my character moves 2400px then tile ends.Because this game is a side-scrolling game.